# Prestashop How to show another field in informations about customer in BO

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, backoffice

I use prestashop 1.7, I am stuck in the display of a field 'hobbies' which is the phoneNumber in back office prestashop with others fiels like in this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnS2e.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uQb9.png)

i'm new in prestashop and i can't found the files to edit.

I would be grateful if you help me

Comment: i want to have like the others fiels: Phone Number: xx xxx xxx. I really need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This place is not available to alter without modification of order view. There's no hook available in this place. You have two choices:

- you can override back-office view
- you can hook into displayBackOfficeHeader, check if current controller is this one related to Orders, and if so, load your data to JS variable with `Media::addJsDef` and insert it with JS too

If you need further assistance, let me know.